# Prime numbers direct counter

Tags: counter

How can I design a prime numbers  counter up to 63?I need to find a rule for the bits? I know how to usually design counters but this one seems kind of difficult since there are so many numbers

Comment: so many? there is only 18.

Comment: Do you mean a counter that resets at a programmable limit, and you only need implement prime limits? Or a counter that counts up 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 etc?

Comment: Discrete logic, Verilog, VHDL, Microcontroller?

Comment: jk ffs @oldfart

Comment: @JonRB so I need to find all the prime numbers,isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @lola, yes its called BRAM and storing these 18 values in. Why overcomplicate the issue.

Comment: If you HAVE to do it in JK FFs: forget about the calculation, find the above mentioned 18 numbers and make a block of logic which generates those 18 numbers. Otherwise a ROM, PLD or small FPGA will do the job.

Comment: I don't know what a *prime numbers counter* is supposed to be.  We do engineering here, not hand waving.  Quite possibly someone will answer, then you say "No, that's not what I mean.".  Closing as unclear.

Comment: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61 as 63 **isn't a prime** then you can't count up to 63, just 61. As regards a 'pattern' mathematicians have been looking for one for centuries.

Comment: Is 63 a prime number? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Use a counter that goes from 0 to 17: $$\begin{align*}B_5&=A_4+A_3A_2+A_3A_1A_0\\
B_4&=A_4+\overline{A_3}A_2A_1+A_3\overline{A_2}\overline{A_1}+A_2A_1A_0+A_3\overline{A_2}\overline{A_0}\\
B_3&=A_4+A_2\overline{A_1}+A_3\overline{A_1}A_0+A_3A_1\overline{A_0}\\
B_2&=A_3\overline{A_2}+A_3A_1+\overline{A_2}A_1+A_4A_0+\overline{A_3}A_2\overline{A_1}A_0\\
B_1&=\overline{A_3}A_1A_0+A_3A_1\overline{A_0}+\overline{A_3}\overline{A_1}\overline{A_0}+A_3A_2\overline{A_1}A_0+\overline{A_2}\overline{A_1}\overline{A_0}+\overline{A_4}\overline{A_3}\overline{A_2}A_0\\
B_0&=A_4+A_3+A_2+A_1+A_0\end{align*}$$

Comment: I mean a counter that counts up in the loop 1-2-3-5-7 @Neil_UK Sorry I wasn't clear enough I'll try to be more detailed next time

Comment: Except for 2, 3, & 5, all Prime numbers Mod 6 will equal 1 or 5.

Comment: @Optionparty 5 is not a exception.

Comment: @King: Seriously?  Just factor it, which can be done by inspection for such a low number.  It should be immediately obvious it is divisible by 3.  That leaves 21, which is 7 * 3.  In the end, you get  63 = 3^2 * 7.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I should have included some sarcasm haha :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a homework question without minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cheat, then by all means generate the prime numbers off line, put them in a memory, and clock them out, it will be quicker and easier. But would it be cool? I don't think so.

This is a step towards a possible answer. It would be nice if it worked perfectly. As it is, it almost works, so it's only fairly cool. For how to fix it, see the end of the answer.

There are no lookup tables to generate, the solution really does compute the primes, using only counters and gates. You don't need to find specific rules for the bits.

What's really cool about it is that the limit of 63 stated in the OP is a soft limit in this solution. It is trivial to, and obvious how to, extend the solution to an arbitrary limit, that is a limit determined by your funds.

While this implementation may be new, the idea does go back somewhat. Back to before 200 BCE in fact, to [Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

A number P is prime if it has no factors (other than the trivial 1 and P). A number mP has factors m and P. If you build a P state counter (otherwise known as a modulo counter), reset it to zero, and clock it once, its output will be 1, twice and it will be 2, P times and it will be back to 0 again, mP times and its output will also be back to 0.

This allows us to see whether a number has any factor P. Clock two counters at the same time, one counting to at least Nmax to generate a number N, the other counting modulo P. When the latter's output is zero, P divides N.

If a composite number N has two factors, then one of them will always be \$<\sqrt N\$. I'll state this without proof, which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader. That means for numbers up to 64, we need only test with prime factors less than 8, or 2, 3, 5 and 7.

We build 5 counters. The N counter, which counts up to at least 63. Then we build 4 modulo counters of length 2, 3, 5 and 7 counts. This can be done several ways, the most obvious of which is to decode the counters' outputs, and reset the counter when it reaches our target count.

As the N counter counts up, if any of the modulo counters is at 0, N has a factor, and cannot be prime. We therefore OR together all the tests for modulo counters being zero, and call composite if any are zero.

Here is a spreadsheet showing the results of implementing this algorithm for N up to 63

```
N   P2  P3  P5  P7  prime
0   0   0   0   0   FALSE
1   1   1   1   1   TRUE
2   0   2   2   2   FALSE
3   1   0   3   3   FALSE
4   0   1   4   4   FALSE
5   1   2   0   5   FALSE
6   0   0   1   6   FALSE
7   1   1   2   0   FALSE
8   0   2   3   1   FALSE
9   1   0   4   2   FALSE
10  0   1   0   3   FALSE
11  1   2   1   4   TRUE
12  0   0   2   5   FALSE
13  1   1   3   6   TRUE
14  0   2   4   0   FALSE
15  1   0   0   1   FALSE
16  0   1   1   2   FALSE
17  1   2   2   3   TRUE
18  0   0   3   4   FALSE
19  1   1   4   5   TRUE
20  0   2   0   6   FALSE
21  1   0   1   0   FALSE
22  0   1   2   1   FALSE
23  1   2   3   2   TRUE
24  0   0   4   3   FALSE
25  1   1   0   4   FALSE
26  0   2   1   5   FALSE
27  1   0   2   6   FALSE
28  0   1   3   0   FALSE
29  1   2   4   1   TRUE
30  0   0   0   2   FALSE
31  1   1   1   3   TRUE
32  0   2   2   4   FALSE
33  1   0   3   5   FALSE
34  0   1   4   6   FALSE
35  1   2   0   0   FALSE
36  0   0   1   1   FALSE
37  1   1   2   2   TRUE
38  0   2   3   3   FALSE
39  1   0   4   4   FALSE
40  0   1   0   5   FALSE
41  1   2   1   6   TRUE
42  0   0   2   0   FALSE
43  1   1   3   1   TRUE
44  0   2   4   2   FALSE
45  1   0   0   3   FALSE
46  0   1   1   4   FALSE
47  1   2   2   5   TRUE
48  0   0   3   6   FALSE
49  1   1   4   0   FALSE
50  0   2   0   1   FALSE
51  1   0   1   2   FALSE
52  0   1   2   3   FALSE
53  1   2   3   4   TRUE
54  0   0   4   5   FALSE
55  1   1   0   6   FALSE
56  0   2   1   0   FALSE
57  1   0   2   1   FALSE
58  0   1   3   2   FALSE
59  1   2   4   3   TRUE
60  0   0   0   4   FALSE
61  1   1   1   5   TRUE
62  0   2   2   6   FALSE
63  1   0   3   0   FALSE
```

This is the equation for the prime column on the N=62 line

```
=not(or(B62=0, C62=0, D62=0, E62=0))
```

You immediately see the flaw. It does mark 1 as prime, though misses 2, 3, 5 and 7.

Why? Because for those prime numbers, the modulo counter is zero!

There are several possible fixes.

One is a change of definition, which feels a bit cheaty to me. It generates all the primes except the primes up to sqrt(Nmax).

Another is to gate in a decode of those missing primes. As there are only a small number, this might be reasonable, but it's ugly, and spoils the extension to an arbitrary limit I was so excited about.

The third, and in my mind the best fix, is to add an extra latch per modulo counter, which is reset initially, and gets set when the counter rolls over for the first time. Use this to mask the offending zero that the counter produces. This in fact does represent a logical implementation of the language of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, of putting the first of each prime number into the table. The advantage of this is that all modulo channels are then identical, apart from the length of the counter, which restores the triviality of extending the solution to arbitrary Nmax.

Perhaps you need a counter that produces only the primes in sequence? Wrap a clock oscillator and an enable gate round the this counter, so that it will count quickly to skip any composite numbers, and stop on the primes. Add an output latch if you really don't want to see those composite numbers flash by at the output.

Comment: It misses alot more.... 51 it really is simpler to seed RAM with the 18 prime number and then do a simple counter to index BRAM

Comment: @JonRB  51??? So you think 17*3 is prime do you? Of course it's simpler for any small finite number to calculate them offline and put them in a ROM. But I maintain that to generate them, an arbitrary number of them, is way cooler.

Answer (score 0):

*Cobbling together bits from the comments...*

Realistically, the simplest solution is going to be a straight binary counter, with the counter outputs acting as the address inputs to a ROM.

There are only 18 prime numbers in your range, so that's a 5-bit counter.  The ROM therefore needs at least 5 address bits and at least 6 data bits out.

You'll need to work out what to do when you hit the end.  Perhaps use a spare data bit in the ROM to encode "end of sequence" and use that to reset the counter to zero.

*If you can find a general formula for calculating the next prime number, I suggest you write it up and send it to a mathematical journal.  Someone will probably nominate you for the Fields medal.*